# Ajuda com concatenar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, moodle

Preciso passar uma variável dentro de um array de itens, um parâmetro que só aceita string, porem quando passo uma variável a API não aceita, diz que o parâmetro está incorreto.

Melhor explicando:

```
 var userstocreate = [
 {
     username: 'aqui a variavel',
     password: 'senha',
     firstname: 'nome',
     lastname: 'sobrenome',
     email: 'email'
 }
```

No username onde fica 'aqui a variavel' tenho que passar entre aspas simples.

Alguém tem uma luz para conseguir fazer isso?

Consegui, obrigado pela ajuda de todos ficou assim.

```
   var userstocreate = [
   {
    username: '' + usuario + '',
    password: 'E@d123456',
    firstname: '' + primeiro +'',
    lastname: '' + lastname + '',
    email: '' + email + ''
   }
 ];

var primeiro = this.firstname.toString();
var usuario = this.username.toString();
var lastname = this.lastname.toString();
var email = this.email.toString();
```

Comment: A variavel que voce esta está tentando passar ja é uma string?

Comment: Sim
  var usuario = this.username;
é uma string, ja tentei converter

eu ja criei uma variavel por exemplo var nome = "nomedousuario";
ai quando tento colocar no usernaem : nome. 
não funciona de jeito nenhum.

Comment: Já tentou passar ela sem nenhum tipo de conversao?

Comment: Já tentei raphael, essa API é do MOODLE eu preciso fazer um cadastro de aluno vindo do banco da instituição, já ta tudo pronto, ja listei os alunos, já tem o serviço, que traz tudo em json, ta tudo prontinho, só preciso colocar a variável dentro do array de usuários.

Comment: ja fiz isso.
 var usuario = "usuarioagoravai"
    var userstocreate = [
                        {   
                            username: usuario,
                            password: 'E@d123456',
                            firstname: 'testfirstname1',
                            lastname: 'testlastname1',
                            email: 'estagio3@toledoprudente.edu.br'
                            
                         }
                     ];

Comment: tenta essa concatenação, username: '"'+ username + '"',

Comment: @YuriRodrigues Poste como resposta ao invés de editar o conteúdo da pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar caracteres de escape como o `\'` para primeiro obter o valor da variavel e tornar esse uma string

```
username: "\'"+ variavel +"\'",
```

Comment: não deu :(
responseText: "{"exception":"invalid_parameter_exception","errorcode":"invalidparameter","message":"Valor inv\u00e1lido de par\u00e2metro detectado"

Esse é o erro que da, quando tento passar algo sem ser dentro das aspas simples

Comment: então seu problema é que a API só aceitaria que você passa-se o valor 'nome' e não "nome", muito estranho isso, por padrão o javascript encapsula string com aspas duplas, não sei se daria de converter para simples

Comment: Eu posso passar "nome", a api aceita, só não aceita uma variável.

Comment: @YuriRodrigues usando essa resposta, não seria apenas `''+variavel+''`?

Comment: Ja tentei

var userstocreate = [
                                                  {
                                                      username: ''+usuario+'',
                                                      password: 'E@d123456',
                                                      firstname: 'Julia',
                                                      lastname: 'testefinal',
                                                      email: 'testefinal@hotmail.com'
                                                  }
                              ];

e não vai.

Comment: Galera funcionou! Nossa Muito obrigado mesmo todo mundo!
username: '' + usuario + '',
fim assim. Muito obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

Sinceramente eu nao entendi.
Você quer que o username tenha um valor de uma variavel?

Se for isso tem muito jeto de fazer.

```
var akira = "texto"
```

exemplo;

```
var userstocreate = [
    {
        username: akira,
        password: 'senha',
        firstname: 'nome',
        lastname: 'sobrenome',
        email: 'email'
    }
]
```

ou

```
var userstocreate = [
    {
        username: '', //opcional definir
        password: 'senha',
        firstname: 'nome',
        lastname: 'sobrenome',
        email: 'email'
    }
]
userstocreate[0].username = akira
```

Comment: Aonde está username preciso passar uma variável, apenas isso, porem preciso passar ela como string, ja tentei converter a variável, já tentei tudo mas não funciona, se eu não passar dentro das aspas simples a API não aceita, entendeu?

Comment: Akira, utilize os campos dos comentários para perguntar a respeito da real necessidade de quem pergunta, isso facilita tanto na elaboração de uma resposta precisa, quanto evita conteúdo como "Sinceramente eu nao entendi. Você quer que o username tenha um valor de uma variavel?" no corpo da resposta.